# try & catch in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

The `try{}catch` construct is common to C++, Java & related languages. In the iOS SDK is there and any functionality like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try-catch exception handling practice for iPhone/Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678438/try-catch-exception-handling-practice-for-iphone-objective-c)

Comment: Some advice since it looks like you're coming over from the Java world: in iOS exceptions are rarely used for program control. An exception almost always means that the programmer did something wrong and it should be fixed. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC

Comment: Here's a better link that describes the role of exceptions in Cocoa/iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
@try {
    // Try something
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e); 
}
@finally {
    // Added to show finally works as well
}
```

Comment: Curious: is there EVER a situation where the exception caught would not be of type `NSException`? More importantly, is there ever a situation in which the `NSLog` could blow up? If you think this is a different question, let me know and I'll ask it properly.

Comment: Yes, you can capture a specific exception or a custom exception. Check out the example under "Catching Different Types of Exception". http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html