# How to get the exact point where an exception was raised?

Tags: iphone, ipad, exception

I am developing a project in which I placed a block of code in a try block.

The block contains 5 statements in order to assign a image to a imageView (I have 5 imageviews to which I am adding images from resource folder). The flow jumps to catch block if there is no image in the resource folder.

I wanted to know the exact statement out of the five where the exception is getting raised so that I can assign the image a `nil`.

```
@try {
    if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
        cell.bookImageView1.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+0].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView2.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+1].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView3.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+2].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView4.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+3].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView5.image=nil;
    }else {
        cell.bookImageView1.image=nil;
        cell.bookImageView2.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+0].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView3.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+1].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView4.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+2].titleImage;
        cell.bookImageView5.image=[[KitabooBookListDataSource sharedDataSource] bookAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+3].titleImage;
    }
}


@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"catch block");
    NSLog(@"array of exception %@",[e callStackReturnAddresses]);
    //NSMutableArray *catchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[e callStackReturnAddresses]];
    //[[catchArray lastObject] ]=nil;
}
```

Comment: Which type of exception is raised? The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 2):

You generally shouldn't use exceptions for program flow. Instead, modify your `bookAtIndex:` method to return nil when the index is out of bounds... or even more appropriately, you should just check the number of books before trying to get each one.

Read [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802095/what-are-the-best-practices-for-exceptions-returning-no-nil-in-objective-c/6802326#6802326) for more about exceptions and exception handling.